# Не удаляет элемент массива, который по модулю больше 10

Tags: javascript, массивы

выводит исходный массив, что и был введен
не использую deletе, так как он оставит дыру в массиве...
Может, я неверно понимаю смысла метода splice? помогите(

```
    let gg=Math.abs(10);
    var newArray1=new Array();
    for(i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
    {
        if (newArray[i]<gg)
        {
            newArray1.push(newArray[i]);
            //newArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else if (newArray[i]>gg)
        {
            delete newArray[i];
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('modul').value=newArray1;
```

Все! поняла, где ошибка) В условии надо было по модулю взять сами элементы массива, а не сравнивать с модулем десятки) Спасибо большое всем!!

Comment: "элемент, который по модулю больше 10" - где?

Comment: Math.abs(10) — это просто 10. abs должен быть с другой стороны)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во-первых удалять элементы массива, идя по этому массиву, очень нехорошо - лезут побочные эффекты зачастую (поскольку этот процесс хождения по изменяемому массиву не совсем очевидный)

лучше собрать новый массив пройдя по старому массиву

например, оставить в массиве только нечётные числа:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,]

arr = arr.filter(value => value % 2)

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Модификация массива по месту без создания другого массива всё же порой необходима.

Смотри комментарии в коде ниже.

```js
{ // Обозначим проблему
  const a = [1, 15, 7, 12, 15, 9, 8, 11, 3];

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (Math.abs(a[i]) > 10) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log('Некоторые элементы пропущены', JSON.stringify(a));
}

{ // Решение проблемы в лоб
  const a = [1, 15, 7, 12, 15, 9, 8, 11, 3];

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (Math.abs(a[i]) > 10) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
      // следующий элемент массива теперь лежит по текущему индексу
      // Исправим переменную цикла
      i--;
    }
  }
  console.log('Ок. Модификация итератора', JSON.stringify(a));
}

{ // Обход проблемы
  const a = [1, 15, 7, 12, 15, 9, 8, 11, 3];
  // Проблема вообще не возникнет, если смотреть элементы от хвоста к голове
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (Math.abs(a[i]) > 10) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log('Ок. Обратный проход', JSON.stringify(a));
}

{ // Ручное управление
  const a = [1, 15, 7, 12, 15, 9, 8, 11, 3];
  let insert = 0;
  let check = 0;
  while (check < a.length) {
    if (!(Math.abs(a[check]) > 10)) {
        // Помещаем значение на своё место
        a[insert++] = a[check]; 
    }
    ++check;
  }
  a.length = insert; // Устанавливаем новую длину массива
  console.log('Ручной фильтр', JSON.stringify(a));
  // Казалось бы, это прекрасно(ведь ничего лишнего!), 
  // но обычно встроенные функции вроде splice работают 
  // настолько быстрее ручных манипуляций, что сложно добиться лучших результатов. 
  // Хотя, на больших массивах можно заметить улучшение)
}
```